# Search partial textstring and replace with corresponding cell

Tags: search, replace, google-sheets, find

FormAnswer:

A(email) | B(name)

Students:

A(name) | B(uid)

What I want
If 1234@domain.com is registered on page FormAnswer: A(email)
Look at Students for "1234" in B(uid) and grab value of A(name) and
Then write this in FormAnswer: B(name)

This works - but only for first row
IF( ISNUMBER( FIND( (LEFT(F1:F;LEN(F1:F)-10)) ; (Elever!C1:C) ) ) ; (Elever!B1:B) ; "Elevens navn mangler" )

What I want, Vol II
Code looking through entire column accordingly with new signups.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try and put the correct tags into your question so that people can find it who can answer (like the language you're writing it)

Comment: I figure Google Sheets says all and i'm not sure about the tags. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't a clue either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess based on the information at hand:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(F:F;"^(.+?)@");{Elever!C:C&""\Elever!B:B};2;0);"Elevens navn mangler"))`

Comment: Google says: Extends number of rows and produces 50000 :-D

Comment: IF( ISNUMBER( FIND( (LEFT(F1:F;LEN(F1:F)-10)) ; (Elever!C1:C) ) ) ; (Elever!B1:B) ; "Elevens navn mangler" ) This one actually works but ONLY for the first row. If 1234@domain.com is at row 14 it returns "Elevens navn mangler" (students name is missing) I have tried F, F1, F0 and F:F1000 but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: In what cell are you placing the formula?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fhrd6dvvit_chzP6ifwRQ5BWUwuLnsVu4TL1LdezHVM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You did it! I just changed F:F to F1:F to prevent Sheets from adding up to limit 50.000 rows. Thank you :-D

Comment: That's OK. You actually changed it to F2:F as you were starting in the second row (F:F and F1:F are functionally the same).